# Twitter service stop send direct message when update

Tags: c#, twitter, twitter-oauth

My Twitter service was working fine. When I update Twitter service every thing working fine, but send direct messages and receive messages stop working.

Why this issue is appearing.

Comment: It is impossible to answer your question with such a few information. Show your service code and tell what do you mean by _stop working_ exactly. Write your exception or error message.

Comment: Please take time to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you explain what specifically you did 'when I update twitter service' - do you mean changed the API version? Do you have the correct scopes in your oauth token for direct messages?